# Can't connect win 10 machine to hosted server, but my mac connects

Tags: windows, vpn, windows-server-2012-r2

I have one server 2012 instance in the google cloud framework running server 2012. I have setup routing access, and I can connect to the server with my mac.

With Windows, it doesn't connect. In the event view it returns error code 800, and the error message itself says:

> The network connection between your computer and the VPN server was interrupted. This can be caused by a problem in the VPN transmission and is commonly the result of internet latency or simply that your VPN server has reach capacoity.

I want to connect via L2TP with a pre-shared secret. Again, set this up on the mac -> works. On win10 -> fails.

Ultimately I need to connect the WIN machine to the server, so where am I going wrong? Client or Server?

Answer (score 0):

Ugh.

So apparently Windows needs a regkey update.

Here's a link to what needs to be done.

https://www.rebelpeon.com/synology-l2tpipsec-vpn/